# Getting the source of this click event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dynamically created buttons with the same class on my page and when I try to call a function on the click of the button, the function gets called for all of the buttons with the same class.
I want the function to be called for this click event only.
Here is my function:-

```
$(".js-btn-plus").click(function (e) {
var link = $(e.target);
var val = link.next('.value').text();

val++

link.next('.value').text(val);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well? Ideally your code should work just fine. But we need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe generate unique ID for the button and use that as an event reference instead of the class?

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` returns a string. Convert the string `val` to a number

```
val = Number(val) + 1
```

or

```
val = +val++
```

Comment: lets suppose I have 5 buttons with the class .js-btn-plus, then I simply want my function to be executed only for the button which is clicked and not for all the buttons with the class .js-btn-plus.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you provide some sample HTML to alongside the JQuery?

From what I can see you may want to have a look at using `$(this)` instead of `e.target`

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-btn-plus', function() {
    var val = parseInt( $(this).find('.value').text() );
    val++;
    $(this).find('.value').text(val);
});
```

Not 100% sure what it is that you're trying to achieve, there may be a better way of doing it if you could explain a little bit more and provide some HTML to go alongside your question.

Edit: Using the 'on' function allows you to dynamically bind the function events instead of having them have a listener fire when the script is loaded and executed.

Comment: lets suppose I have 5 buttons with the class .js-btn-plus, then I simply want my function to be executed only for the button which is clicked and not for all the buttons with the class .js-btn-plus

Comment: My reply should be what you're after then, give it a try and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$(".js-btn-plus").click(function (e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('.value').text());
    val++;
    $(this).next('.value').text(val);
});
```